# Hadoop fs -test if file exists

Tags: hadoop

Earlier, I ran this command on a hadoop client machine without issue:

`hadoop fs -cp test.log hdfs://remote-hadoop-server.com:/user/testuser`

Now I want to test if file is there(its there!) using this command, but I got this error:

`hadoop fs -test -e hdfs://remote-hadoop-server.com:/user/testuser/test.log`

`-test: Too many arguments: expected 1 but got 2`
`Usage: hadoop fs [generic options] -test -[defsz] <path>`

Comment: try `hdfs dfs ..` instead of `hadoop fs ..` http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/hadoop/3870/hadoop-commands/20034/hadoop-v2-commands

Comment: @Ambrish, still doesnt work